# Strange Behavior of jQuery UI Dialog Box in Mobile Safari when in an iframe

Tags: mobile, jquery, safari

I have one page inside of another using an iframe and when I call .dialog from within the iframe on Mobile Safari (4.3 and 5.0.1 are all I have access to) the iframe scrolls to about half way down the iframe and the dialog box is displayed a little above half way down the iframe.  I've been able to get the dialog to appear where I want it using the .position function but the iframe still scrolls to the half way point of the iframe at least the first time.

Can anyone lend a hand on trying to figure this out?